# Confused about adjectives

Tags: grammar-identification, conjugation

I have a few questions.

For example in the sentence

> Ich habe viele Freunde.

1. What form does viel take relating to this chart 
   https://www.verbformen.com/declension/adjectives/?w=viel
2. What makes adjectives have genders? Can you give some examples
3. What is constitutes as a plural adjective?
4. Freunde in the above sentence is Akkusativ, yes?

Comment: Dear Yozansen, this forum is not intended to be for "ask questions whatever you want". Good questions here show a certain level of research done by the author of the question, and they also should be potentially useful also for others. (See the community rules.) Also, you should restrict a question to one topic.

Comment: Yeah, like the question above mine asking about the definition of 'schon' with 6 upvotes. Come on, even you can find the various meaning of schon with a google/ youtube search or reverso context. What a joke.

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=schon+german+meaning

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. It's accusative plural strong.
2. Adjectives do not have genders. The nouns they belong to have. If you
   make an adjective a noun by itself (e.g. der/die/das Kleine), it has
   all three genders.
3. Freunde is a plural form, the adjectives associated to it must follow that.
4. Yes.

Comment: Liebe Janka, indem Sie Off-Topic-Fragen beantworten, erwecken Sie den Eindruck, dass solche Fragen erwünscht wären.